# Get specific values from relational db

Tags: php, sql, html, codeigniter-3

Hey what im trying to get here is a single array that pull all images_links from another db.

First DB:

```
id | text | user | date
 1 | heya |    8 |   02
```

Second DB

```
id | image_link | post_id |
 1 | image1.jpg |       1 |
 2 | image2.jpg |       1 |
 3 | image3.jpg |       1 |
```

My best result so far:

```
| text | user | image_link | date
| heya |    8 | image1.jpg |   02
| heya |    8 | image2.jpg |   02
| heya |    8 | image3.jpg |   02
```

If my post has only one image or none the result goes right, but if it has more than one image it gerenate 1 extra row for each aditional image, that is the problem

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` should do the trick.

Comment: Can you show us what result you're expecting? It's very unclear since the result you say you're getting doesn't actually include any duplicates.

Comment: sorry, i was expecting only one array with like: Array ( [text] => heya [user] => 8 [image_link] => array( [0] => image1.jpg [1] => image2.jpg [2] => image3.jpg) [date] => 02 ), i know its propably impossible to do with only sql, but i can use like 3 query and merge maybe ?, idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a column to contain all images, use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT 
    text,
    user, 
    date, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(image_link) AS images
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.post_id
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Then on PHP side use `explode` to convert comma-separated string into array:

```
$images = explode(',', $row['images']);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `DISTINCT` statement to get the unique data without duplicates

```
"SELECT DISTINCT image_link FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.post_id";
```

Comment: Distinct won't help with this. The rows aren't actually duplicates (the images are different.) The OP needs to show us what the expected result is, since it's super unclear.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes i agree . i think my update may suit the OP, since he need just a table with non duplicated values.

Comment: If you look at the example data and the example output (that the OP says is the current result), this would produce the exact same result (except from the post info). I don't think the OP really knows what the expected result is here :-)